# Conditional Probability - truth/lie

Tags: probability

The probability that two poker players speak truth is 3/5 and 2/3.  A card is drawn from the pack and they both agree that it is a queen.  What is the probability that it is really a queen ?

**My approach:-**

4 cases possible for A and B based on one saying Truths and Lies (TT,TF,FT,FF)

Case 1:- Both speaking truth and it is really a queen = 3/5 * 2/3 * 4/52

Case 2 and 3:- One person saying truth and other lie will not be possible as it would lead to an inconsistency because it is given that both agree it to be queen

Case 4:-Both speaking a lie, and it is not a queen = 2/5 * 1/3 * 48/52 = 8/65

Answer= 12/65

Answer given in book is 1/5

Can this be solved using probability tree diagram ?

Comment: These problems are always so vague. If they lie, how do they choose which lie to say?  It's so much clearer if everything is a Yes/No question.  Say, for instance, each player is asked "Is this card a Queen?" with Yes/No being the only permitted responses.  That might clarify the problem.

Comment: Beyond that, this is a routine application of Bayes' Theorem.  (N.B. I have no idea how you got $\frac {12}{65}$.)

Comment: @lulu cant figure out how Bayes is used here

Comment: It is used in the standard way.  Denominator is the probability that the observed results can be observed, numerator is the portion of that which is explained by the desired cause.  Note:  you also need to make some assumption of dependence.  I imagine you meant to say that the players choose to lie or not, independent of reality and independent of each other.

Comment: yes @lulu , I meant the same, how should I take the dependence here ?

Comment: My point was that the problem should have specified the relevant independence.  That kind of thing shouldn't be left to readers to guess at.

Comment: @lulu , in the answer given below by ash4fun, why are we not considering a case when the card is a queen and both A and B are lying ?

Comment: You should go over this with the author of that solution.

Comment: That said, I do not understand your question.  If the card is a Queen and they both say it is a Queen, then obviously they are not lying so the case you mention does not exist.

Comment: I expect that the difficulty you are having here stems from the poor phrasing of the problem.  I suggest clarifying the question as:  "prior to the deal, each player decides whether they will lie or not using the given probabilities.  Their decision is independent of whatever the other decides and it is independent of the deal itself.  Then, they will be asked whether the card is a Queen or not, to which they can 
 reply Yes/No only.  "  I think that phrasing removes the ambiguities in the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the event that the first player says the card is a queen, $B$ be the event that the second player says the card is a queen, and $Q$ be the event that a queen is actually drawn. By the problem statement, we can reasonably assume that $A$ and $B$ are independent of each other, when $Q$ is held fixed.

Then we are given $P(Q),P(A|Q),P(B|Q),P(A|Q^C),P(B|Q^C)$, and we are looking to find $P(Q|AB)$.

By Bayes' Theorem, we know:

$$P(Q|AB)=\frac{P(AB|Q)\cdot P(Q)}{P(AB)}
\\=\frac{P(AB|Q)\cdot P(Q)}{P(AB|Q)\cdot P(Q)+P(AB|Q^C)\cdot P(Q^C)}
\\=\frac{P(A|Q)\cdot P(B|Q)\cdot P(Q)}{P(A|Q)\cdot P(B|Q)\cdot P(Q)+P(A|Q^C)\cdot P(B|Q^C)\cdot P(Q^C)}
\\=\frac{(3/5)(2/3)(1/13)}{(3/5)(2/3)(1/13)+(2/5)(1/3)(12/13)}
\\=\frac{6}{6+24}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Comment: The probability of A saying truth is given 3/5, why did you take that as probability of saying queen instead

Comment: @Fin27 ash4fun did not take that as the probability of $A$ saying queen "instead". $P(A|Q)$ means the probability that says it is a queen given that it is a queen. That is the equivalent of saying that $A$ told the truth. In the denominator $P(A|Q^C)$ has a probability of $2/5$ since that is $A$ saying it is a queen after we already know it is not a queen.

Comment: @SlipEternal  why are we considering the case when there is no queen ?

Comment: This solution is being given in my textbook also , but I am finding difficult to understand it.  The first event is drawing a queen and the second event is whether they are saying truth or lie ?

Comment: I don't understand your question... You don't know if the card is a queen or not. Either it is a queen, and A and B both say it is a queen, or it is not a queen, and A and B both say it is a queen anyway. Unless the only card in the deck is a queen (in which case there is a 100% chance you draw a queen), then you have to consider the possibility the card is not a queen.

Comment: Perhaps I can explain it another way. $P(Q|AB)$ means assume both A and B have stated it is a queen (they could be lying or telling the truth. We don't know). What is the probability the card is a queen. $P(AB|Q)$ means assume the card is a queen. What is the probability that both A and B say it is a queen? Once you know it is a queen, they can only say it if they are telling the truth. Thus, this is the equivalent of saying what is the probability they both tell the truth.

Comment: On the other hand, $P(AB|Q^C)$ means assume the card is not a queen, but A and B say it is a queen anyway. This answer assumes that is the equivalent of saying, "What is the probability they both lie?"

Comment: Does truth here means they are agreeing for a queen and lying indicates that they disagree after looking the card, irrespective of if there is a queen or not on the card ?

Comment: @SlipEternal , can you please show what exactly is being asked or given with the help of a probability tree ? I guess that is easier to visualise

Comment: Also where is the case for when the card shows Queen, and both of them disagree to it ?

Comment: @Fin27 I moved the discussion to chat.

Comment: which chat ?@SlipEternal

Answer (score 0):

If, as lulu suggested, A and B choose their lie with a uniform distribution, we wind up with a vastly different answer. The problem can be broken down as follows:

Define $Q, A_Q, B_Q$ to be the events that the drawn card is a queen, $A$ says the card is a queen, and $B$ says the card is a queen respectively.

Then, you have the following truth table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}Q & A_Q & B_Q & \text{Prob} \\ \hline T & T & T & \tfrac{1}{13}\cdot \tfrac{3}{5}\cdot \tfrac{2}{3} = \tfrac{2}{65} \\ T & T & F & \tfrac{1}{13} \cdot \tfrac{3}{5} \cdot \tfrac{1}{3} = \tfrac{1}{65} \\ T & F & T & \tfrac{1}{13} \cdot \tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{2}{3} = \tfrac{4}{195} \\ T & F & F & \tfrac{1}{13}\cdot \tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{1}{3} = \tfrac{2}{195} \\ F & T & T & \tfrac{12}{13}\cdot \left(\tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right)\cdot \left(\tfrac{1}{3}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right) = \tfrac{1}{1170} \\ F & T & F & \tfrac{12}{13}\left(\tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right)\left(1-\tfrac{1}{3}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right)=\tfrac{7}{234} \\ F & F & T & \tfrac{12}{13}\left(1-\tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right)\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right)=\tfrac{29}{1170} \\ F & F & F & \tfrac{12}{13}\left(1-\tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right)\left(1-\tfrac{1}{3}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}\right) = \tfrac{203}{234}\end{array}$$

Note: I am assuming a uniform distribution of lies So, if the card is not a queen, and they say it is a queen, not only is it the probability of them lying, it is also the probability that their lie happened to be a queen. So, $P(Q^C\cap A_Q^C)$ is the probability that it is not a queen and $A$ says a different card. $A$ will tell the truth with probability $\tfrac{3}{5}$. $A$ will say it is a queen with probability $\tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12}$. $A$ will lie and say it is another card (that is not a queen) with probability $\tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{11}{12}$. For example, if the actual card is a king, he will say it is not a king with probability $\tfrac{2}{5}$, but the chosen lie (ace through queen) is uniformly distributed over that event. So, each individual card that is not a king has its own $\tfrac{2}{5}\cdot \tfrac{1}{12} = \tfrac{1}{30}$ chance of being told.

Next, we add up the probabilities to ensure we have a total probability space:

$$\dfrac{2}{65}+\dfrac{1}{65}+\dfrac{4}{195}+\dfrac{2}{195}+\dfrac{1}{1170}+\dfrac{7}{234}+\dfrac{29}{1170}+\dfrac{203}{234} = 1$$

And indeed we do. So, unless I made a calculation error, we have:

$$P(Q|A_Q\cap B_Q) = \dfrac{P(Q\cap A_Q\cap B_Q)}{P(A_Q \cap B_Q)} = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{65}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{2}{65}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{1170}\right)} = \dfrac{36}{37}$$

Another note: This also assumes all events are independent (players choose to lie independently of reality and each other). This seems like another valid answer to the original problem since it was not clearly worded.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to understand the meaning of Bayes's Formula
$$P(Q|D)=\frac{P(D|Q)P(Q)}{P(D)}$$
First you have an event $Q$ with prior probability $P(Q)$, then we got new evidence about $Q$ after observing $D$,that evidence is incorporated as $P(D|Q)$ to finally evaluate the probability of $Q$ given evidence $D$ using Bayes's Formula.

In your case $Q$ is the event of drawing a Queen with prior $P(Q)= 1/13$,then you got evidence provided by players $D = AB$ as hightlighted @ash4fun. Both players are agree but both can lie, that's why you need to apply Total Probability Law on $AB$ condition respect to $Q$. So thw anwer you are looking for was already provided by @ash4fun.

Comment: But why do we need to use D=AB with respect to Q ?

Comment: @Fin27 the event AB is directly linked to the occurence of Q,  because players are making a stament about the occurence of Q, so the stament can be 'true' when Q occurs, o can be 'false' when Q does not occurs, meaning that the probability of AB being true depends upon occurence of Q.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptualize the event like this:
A draws the card on top. Now, when he 'says' he sees a queen, it can mean one of two things:

1. It was a Queen, and he's telling the truth
2. It wasn't a Queen, and he's lying

B looks at the card and does the same thing

So what does it mean when they 'agree' on the card being a queen? It means they both 'say' it is a queen, i.e.

1. If the card is a queen, they're BOTH telling the truth
2. If the card isn't a queen, they're BOTH lying

[image: Pictorially]

Now, its just an application of Bayes' theorem. (they agree means they agree that it is a Queen)
$$ P(\text{it is Queen} |\text{they agree} ) = \frac { P(\text{they agree}|\text{it is Queen}) \cdot P(\text{it is Queen}) } {P(\text{they agree}|\text{it is Queen})\cdot P(\text{it is Queen}) + P(\text{they agree}|\text{it is not Queen}) \cdot P(\text{it is not Queen})}$$

$$ = \frac{ \frac{6}{15} \cdot \frac{1}{13} }{ \frac{6}{15} \cdot \frac{1}{13}+ \frac{2}{15} \cdot \frac{12}{13} } $$
$$=\frac{1}{5}$$